# Ajax request is too slow

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a page that need to click a number in a table then read another table accordingly from database. I used to use ASP gridview to generate the second table. Then I tried to use jquery ajax. When I need to request 20,000 records, jquery ajax is extremely slow (about 6 seconds to load) while asp gridview is much faster.

**ASPX.VB**

```
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetOrderDetail(ByVal id As String) As String
    Dim orderNum As Integer = Integer.Parse(id)
    Dim sbTable As New StringBuilder
    Dim sql As New StringBuilder

    sql.Append("SELECT oh.[ORDERNO], od.[STYLE], s.[STYLEDESC],od.[COLOR], c.[COLORDESC], od.[SIZE],")
    sql.Append(" SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,0),od.[TOTALQTY])) AS 'Item_Total', och.[TRACKINGNO]")
    sql.Append(" FROM [OrderHeader] AS oh INNER JOIN [test1] AS ocd")
    sql.Append(" ON oh.[ORDERNO] = ocd.[ORDERNO] INNER JOIN [test2] AS och")
    sql.Append(" ON ocd.[FKEY] = och.[PKEY] INNER JOIN [test3] AS od")
    sql.Append(" ON oh.[ORDERNO] = od.[ORDERNO] INNER JOIN [test4] as s")
    sql.Append(" ON s.[STYLE] = od.[STYLE] INNER JOIN [test5] AS c")
    sql.Append(" ON c.[COLOR] = od.[COLOR]")
    sql.Append(" WHERE od.[ORDERNO] =")
    sql.Append(orderNum)
    sql.Append(" GROUP BY oh.[ORDERNO], od.[STYLE], s.[STYLEDESC],od.[COLOR], c.[COLORDESC], od.[SIZE], och.[TRACKINGNO]")

    sql.Append("select [ORDERNO] from [oabcd].[dbo].[OrderHeader] where [ORDERNO] =")
    sql.Append(orderNum)

    Dim connMain As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cmdMain As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim rdrMain As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    connMain = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SsssConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    connMain.Open()
    cmdMain = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connMain)
    rdrMain = cmdMain.ExecuteReader()
    Dim bAlt As Boolean = True
    If rdrMain.HasRows Then
        sbTable.Append("<table class = 'orderDetailTable'>")
        sbTable.Append("<thead>")
        sbTable.Append("<tr>")

        sbTable.Append("<th>")
        sbTable.Append("Order Number")
        sbTable.Append("</th>")

        sbTable.Append("<th>")
        sbTable.Append("Item")
        sbTable.Append("</th>")

        sbTable.Append("<th>")
        sbTable.Append("Color")
        sbTable.Append("</th>")

        sbTable.Append("<th>")
        sbTable.Append("Size")
        sbTable.Append("</th>")

        sbTable.Append("<th>")
        sbTable.Append("Item Total")
        sbTable.Append("</th>")

        sbTable.Append("<th>")
        sbTable.Append("Tracking Number")
        sbTable.Append("</th>")

        sbTable.Append("</tr>")
        sbTable.Append("</thead>")

        sbTable.Append("<tbody>")
        While rdrMain.Read()

            sbTable.Append("<tr>")
            sbTable.Append("<td>")
            sbTable.Append(rdrMain.Item("ORDERNO"))
            sbTable.Append("</td>")
            sbTable.Append("<td>")
            sbTable.Append(rdrMain.Item("STYLEDESC"))
            sbTable.Append("</td>")
            sbTable.Append("<td>")
            sbTable.Append(rdrMain.Item("COLORDESC"))
            sbTable.Append("</td>")
            sbTable.Append("<td>")
            sbTable.Append(rdrMain.Item("Size"))
            sbTable.Append("</td>")
            sbTable.Append("<td>")
            sbTable.Append(rdrMain.Item("Item_Total"))
            sbTable.Append("</td>")
            sbTable.Append("<td>")
            sbTable.Append(rdrMain.Item("TRACKINGNO"))
            sbTable.Append("</td>")
            sbTable.Append("</tr>")
        End While
        sbTable.Append("</tbody>")
        sbTable.Append("</table>")
    End If
    rdrMain.Close()
    cmdMain.Dispose()
    connMain.Close()
    connMain.Dispose()


    Return sbTable.ToString()

End Function
```

**JS**

```
                     $('.orderNumber').on('click', function () {
                    var orderNum = $(this).text();
                    console.log(orderNum);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Order.aspx/GetOrderDetail",
                        data: "{'id' :'" + orderNum + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#orderDetail').html(result.d);
                            $('.orderDetailTable').dataTable({

                            });
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            // Display a generic error for now.
                            alert("Ajax Read Detail Error!");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

I returned a very large string (containing 20,000 records). My question is: Is there any way to improve the code like return other types? Or dont return anything just generate html from asp `GetOrderDetail()` function ? Anything that could make the request faster ? Thanks.

Comment: Like any optimization question, you need to know what's slow before you fix it.  You can use a tool like Chrome's developer tools Network tab to get more detailed information on where the time is going.  It'll break up the time between lookup/connection, waiting for the first byte, and receiving the data.  That will give you a clue as to what needs fixing.

Comment: Maybe not return 20K records at once and implement paging instead?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're returning json data.  It looks like you're returning table data, which would be much bigger, and take longer to put together.

Comment: @slashingweapon I realized my problem which was I should not return a plain string with all the tr,tds. But should it be a DataTable Object or an Array to return?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP, but it looks like you have declared the function to return json data.  You should be able to return an array of dictionaries (or the ASP equivalent) and ASP should json-encode the data for you before sending it to the client.  You will have to add some code to the client to turn it into tables, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a plain string with whole table information, I returned a `Table` class which is a `List` of `Row`.

**ASPX.VB**

The first half is not copied here

```
 rdrMain = cmdMain.ExecuteReader()
    Dim records As New Table
    If rdrMain.HasRows Then

        While rdrMain.Read()
            Dim row As New Row
            row.OrderNum() = Trim(rdrMain.Item("ORDERNO"))
            row.Style() = Trim(rdrMain.Item("STYLEDESC"))
            row.Color() = Trim(rdrMain.Item("COLORDESC"))
            row.Size() = Trim(rdrMain.Item("SIZE"))
            row.Total() = Integer.Parse(Trim(rdrMain.Item("Item_Total")))
            row.Tracking() = Trim(rdrMain.Item("TRACKINGNO"))
            records.RowList.Add(row)
        End While
    End If

    rdrMain.Close()
    cmdMain.Dispose()
    connMain.Close()
    connMain.Dispose()

    Return records
Public Class Row
...
End Class
Public Class Table
...
End Class
```

**JS**

```
 var r = new Array(), j = -1;
                            var html = "<table class ='orderDetailTable'><thead><tr><th class = 'orderDetailNum'>Order</th><th>Style</th>\
            <th>Color</th><th>Size</th><th>Total</th><th>Tracking Number</th></tr></thead><tbody>"
                            for (var key = 0, size = data.d.RowList.length; key < size; key++) {
                                r[++j] = '<tr><td class = "orderDetailNum">';
                                r[++j] = data.d.RowList[key].OrderNum;
                                r[++j] = '</td><td class = "orderStyle">';
                                r[++j] = data.d.RowList[key].Style;
                                r[++j] = '</td><td class = "orderColor">';
                                r[++j] = data.d.RowList[key].Color;
                                r[++j] = '</td><td class = "orderSize">';
                                r[++j] = data.d.RowList[key].Size;
                                r[++j] = '</td><td class = "orderTotal">';
                                r[++j] = data.d.RowList[key].Total;
                                r[++j] = '</td><td class = "orderTracking">';
                                r[++j] = data.d.RowList[key].Tracking;
                                r[++j] = '</td></tr>';
                            }
                            html = html + r.join("") + "</tbody></table>";

                            $('#orderDetail').html(html);
```

It seems faster a little bit. But still slow for 20,000 rows compared ASP GridView. Don't know the performance of LINQ. Maybe need to change the query.